# Sum of two specific values in two different dicts with the same keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am a beginner in Python and have the following problem:

I have two loops, that produce two dictionaries that look like this (of course, much longer):

```
dict1 = {'Manubar': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 222, 23, 45], 'Schorsch': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 122, 65, 44]}

dict2 = {'Manubar': ['string', 'string2', 543, 21, 34], 'Schorsch': ['string', 'string2', 354, 10, 65]}
```

I would now like to sum / multiply the last digits of the same key in dict1 and dict2 and create an new dict that should look like this:

```
dict3 = {'Manubar': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 222, 23, **79** ], 'Schorsch': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 122, 65, **109**]}
```

I tried to merge the two dicts, but that simply overwrites the values.
How do I get to sum the last digits and then put them in a new dict?

Comment: What about the `222` and `23` in the expected output ? Where do they come from ?

Comment: `dict3 = {k: v[:-1] + [v[-1] + dict2[k][-1]] for k, v in dict1.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more verbose, but bit more efficient than the one-liner proposed in the comments:

```py
dict3 = {}
for k in dict1:
    L = dict1[k].copy()
    L[-1] += dict2[k][-1]
    dict3[k] = L
```

Which gives:

```
{'Manubar': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 222, 23, 79], 'Schorsch': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 122, 65, 109]}
```

In case curious, here are the perf comparsion results on my machine, using `timeit`:

```
long way:           0.275188707979396
comprehension way:  0.3881134579423815
```

Comment: Thanks! Better perfomance is good, as the whole querry is already really slow (part hardware, part code) :) Can you explain to me why / what the use of the -1 in L[-1] means? I imagine it is because -1 is not used as a key number so it can be added each loop?

Comment: @JayJericho sure thing. the -1 is just a shorthand to access the last element in a list. to access the second to last element, it would be -2 for instance.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```py
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'Manubar': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 222, 23, 45], 'Schorsch': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 122, 65, 44]}
dict2 = {'Manubar': ['string', 'string2', 543, 21, 34], 'Schorsch': ['string', 'string2', 354, 10, 65]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2, orient='index')
df1.loc[:,5] += df2.loc[:,4]
{i: list(v.values()) for i, v in df1.to_dict('index').items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question, I came up with this:

```
dict3 ={}
keylist=list(dict1.keys())
xxx = 0
for _ in keylist:
    key = keylist[xxx]
    dict3.update({key: [dict1[key][5] + dict2[key][4]]})
    xxx += 1
print(dict3)
```

But it feels a bit sluggish.
How do I improve my code?

Comment: That results in `{'Manubar': [79], 'Schorsch': [109]}` which is different than the requested `{'Manubar': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 222, 23, 79], 'Schorsch': ['string', 'string2', 'string3', 122, 65, 109]}`.  Instead do `dict3 = {k: v[:-1] + [v[-1] + dict2[k][-1]] for k, v in dict1.items()}`

Comment: Thanks! I will save that 1 liner for later use and learning!